# upload image using Facebook browser

Tags: file-upload, web-applications, facebook-apps

I am building a web application where users can upload images.
It is working fine on all devices using any browser, but I have a problem when I launch it in Facebook's browser in android. It also works fine in Facebook when I use it on ios devices, but the problem only occurs on android.
Does anyone have a solution for this?
This is how my input tag looks like:

```
<input id="FileInput" type="file" accept="images/*" ng-show="!IsApp && uploader.queue.length==0"/>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I understood that this is a known issue in Android devices, so currently the solution is to build a native app or use some platform such as phonegap to create a real app.